# android Listview with multiple view and edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

In my project I use multiple groups of TextViews or EditText snd I have such problem - edittext lose focuse and keyboard every time disapear.I need my listview to resize every time I keyboard appear
[image: Example of my views]

My listView is next

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
</ListView>
```

And Manifest Configuration

```
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

I try Some issue but it doesn't work well I have lags when two or more views in focuse.There is issue - I add onTouchListener() to save focuse. And onFocuse() methode where I used saving  focuse for requesting focuse when keyboard is showen

Comment: try: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @Saret When I'm using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Some views are overlapping by keyboard